# Convert Array of Interger to GeoTiff in Java?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, array

I am having the Hashmap of lat,long which is key for the Integer which represents the color value

```
hashmap<Class of lat/long , Integer> // where class of lat/long is my custom class represent a area
```

means at a particular position the color of that area 30x30 meter square represented by one pixel should be decided by the Integer value 
if 1 == Green like wise

that i convert it into the array of a square which could enclose this area 
and created a array as

```
int[max.length][max. width ] // so that they could enclose the area
```

In the array if the point ie int[x][y] this x and y lies on area i made the value 1 for that color Green color.
 But if point does not lies on area its value in array is -1.
as in image 
[image: showing the whole problem]

please help